# How do I execute a Gradle plugin task before another one?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, task, build.gradle

I am using the native-artifacts plugin which defines a number of tasks that extract the Nar dependencies of dependencies that are built elsewhere (and stored in Nexus/Maven). I need to ensure these tasks are called before the build of a binary, otherwise the headers that these Nars include are not found.

My question is, how do I define a system/plugin-defined task as a dependency of one of my tasks?

I'd like something like:

```
binaries.all {binary ->
      dependencies {
        // this next line is now the same as the plugin-defined task I want to have called before
        // before the build takes place
        compile "extractNarDeps${binary.name.capitalize()}"
      }
    }
```

Sadly, this doesn't build. How can I achieve this please?  I have a component called unitTests that is a C++ component and is used to create unitTestsExecutable. I want extractNarDepsxxx called before compileUnitTests is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it was to specify my tasks as dependencies of the plugin's relevant task.  The missing syntax link was in using "tasks" as a means of referencing the tasks in the project.

The answer isn't mine, it was very well explained here: [tasks._applied_plugin_task_name_here.dependsOn(myTask)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101044/gradle-how-do-i-inject-a-task-dependency-into-a-plugin-defined-task)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you have any list named `binaries`? If yes, then you can try something like below in your build.gradle file as dependencies will be executed before your defined task:

```
dependencies {
    binaries.each {binary ->
        // this next line is now the same as the plugin-defined task I want to have called before
        // before the build takes place
        compile "extractNarDeps${binary.name.capitalize()}"
    }
}

// Your defined task here
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work I'm afraid - is there a way of injecting a plugin-defined task as a dependency of another plugin-defined task?