# Gradle: how do I inject a task dependency into a plugin-defined task?

Tags: dependency-injection, gradle, dependencies, task

If a plugin defines a series of tasks, is it possible to inject a dependency into these, such that the dependency is called before the plugin-defined task is executed?

The native-artifacts plugin defines buildNar (and buildNarxxx, where xxx is the platform config) tasks.  It also defines extractNarDepsxxx (where xxx is the platform config for the Nar to be built).  extractNarDeps is not called before builder, so the build fails as required dependencies are not downloaded prior to the attempted build.

How do I inject extractNarDepsxxx as a dependency into buildNarxxx?

Comment: As far as I understood it has nothing to do with DI. You problem can be solved using `dependsOn` and `mustRunAfter`.

Comment: I don't know how to do this for a task that is defined in a plugin that isn't mine, i.e. I can't edit the source of the plugin.  Is this possible?  Do you have an example line of code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Consider the following example:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task someTask
task anotherTask

tasks.classes.mustRunAfter(anotherTask)
tasks.build.dependsOn(someTask)
```

There's a single plugin applied `java` and two custom tasks `someTask` and `anotherTask`.

Task `build` (taken from `java` plugin) `dependsOn` `someTask`. It means that when You run `gradle build` this task will be executed.

Task `classes` `mustRunAfter` `anotherTask`. So when You type `gradle build anotherTask`, `anotherTask` will run before `build`.

Try it. An ask further questions when needed.